# Unity's LayerMask doesn't ignore layer of a child-object (uses parent layer instead)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My parent object has layer A.
My child object (gameobject attached to A in the hierarchy) has layer B.
I want specific raycast to collide with A but not with B.

When I do `Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("A"))` it doesn't ignore the child object.
B should follow position of A and A is networked prefab that must be root so it's hard to make it siblings, any ideas?

Comment: If you want to ignore B layer, this ~LayerMask.NameToLayer("A") should B.

Comment: @Vionix I want to ignore everything but A. For me `~LayerMask.NameToLayer("A")` collides with A and B and nothing else, at first I tought that unity uses layer of a parent, but I managed to split this object and it still collides with B, it drives me crazy. `LayerMask.NameToLayer("A")` collides with everything.

Comment: `LayerMask.NameToLayer("A")` collides with everything but not A and B, I don't understand why A and B layers are treated as the same. When I split these objects runtime the B-layered one still collides as if it was A, maybe they can't be instantiated in parent-child relation, I don't know, I will do more tests later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KiranShahi That's all I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh `LayerMask.NameToLayer` returns index of the layer - not the mask, so to get a mask you do this:
`1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("your_layer_name")`

So solution to my problem is:
`Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("A"))`